# Cleverref package returns an extra parentheses

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I am using the `\cleveref` package to reference subfigures. I am using the `\crefmultiformat` to customize the referencing style. I am trying to achieve Figures 1.1 (a) and (b) but with the attached code I am arriving at 1.1(a) and b). I am not sure how spacing and parentheses are to be defined in the code. Sorry am an amateur LaTeX user.

PFA my MWE:

```latex
    \documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
        \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
    \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefrangelabelformat{figure}{(#3#1#4~to~#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}
    \crefmultiformat{figure}{figures~#2#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#3}
        {and~#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}{,~#2#1#3}{~and~#2#1#3}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.pdf}
            \caption{}
            \label{subfig:apple}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ball.pdf}
            \caption{}
            \label{subfig:ball}
        \end{subfigure}
           \caption{Pictures of (a) Apple and (b) Ball}
           \label{fig:alphabets}
    \end{figure}
        I would like to reference as Figures~1~(a)~and~(b). However, if I use \Cref{subfig:apple,subfig:ball} returns Figures~1(a)and~b).
    \end{document}
```

[image: Subfigure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not very clean code but it returns the correct result for the MWE.

The problem is that the prefix stripping for 1(a) and 1(b) strips the 1( part, because this is the common prefix. To account for the ( that has been stripped off, you can just add a literal `(` character to the format specification, i.e., `and~#2{(\crefstripprefix` etc.

However, this also adds a parenthesis for normal figure ranges without subfigures, e.g., *Figures 1 and (2*. Therefore, the extra parenthesis must only be added when the argument is a subfigure. One way to do that is to check if the counter ends with a closing parenthesis. This can be done with the `xstring` package, that provides a macro `\IfEndWith{string}{suffix}{do if true}{do if false}`, so in this case if the string in the argument `#1` ends with `)` then a `(` is printed, otherwise nothing is printed.

Note that I did not put the extra space in `3(a)` (i.e., `3 (a)`), because I was not sure if this was really desired - if so then some more `xstring` processing can help with that. I did add an extra space before *and*.

Note also that the `caption` package is not needed and also the `\crefrangelabelformat` can be left out for the MWE.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{xstring}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{figures~#2#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#3}
    {~and~#2{\IfEndWith{#1}{)}{(}{}\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}{,~#2#1#3}{~and~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering\fbox{fig1}
\caption{Box with text}
\label{fig:box1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering\fbox{fig2}
\caption{Box with text}
\label{fig:box2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.pdf}
      \caption{Apple}
      \label{subfig:apple}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ball.pdf}
      \caption{Ball}
      \label{subfig:ball}
  \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Pictures of Apple and Ball}
     \label{fig:alphabets}
\end{figure}

I would like to reference as Figures~3~(a)~and~(b). However, if I use \Cref{subfig:apple,subfig:ball} returns Figures~3(a)and~b). Regular figures should not get the extra parenthesis: \Cref{fig:box1,fig:box2}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: for the extra space between `3` and `(a)` the first part of the multiformat should be modified, instead of `#1` (which is the first reference) you can use `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package to change the first parenthesis into a space and a parenthesis. The syntax is `\StrSubstitute{string}{search}{replace}` (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring-en.pdf) of `xstring` for more details). Code:

```
\crefmultiformat{figure}{figures~#2\StrSubstitute{#1}{(}{~(}\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#3}
    {~and~#2{\IfEndWith{#1}{)}{(}{}\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}{,~#2#1#3}{~and~#2#1#3}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marijn, thanks a lot for your answer. The problem is kind of fixed at the moment. As you mentioned I do need that extra space between 3~(a). Could you please help me out with the same. Rest of the format works flawlessly.

Comment: @Harikrishnan see edit for the extra space.